# What is the best way to add CNAM (Caller ID Name) to a SMS processed through twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

My twilio app is just like this [sample app](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-do-i-forward-my-sms-messages-to-another-phone-number)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html');
?>
<Response>
  <Message to="<?=$_REQUEST['PhoneNumber']?>">
  <?=htmlspecialchars(substr($_REQUEST['From'] . ": " . $_REQUEST['Body'], 0, 160))?>
  </Message>
</Response>
```

I would like to add the CNAM (Caller ID name) to the message when I send it on to the destination, but twilio support says:

> We unfortunately do not expose or provide caller ID name in the API response.

Is there any work around or other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<?php
header("content-type: text/xml");
?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Message from="<?php echo $_REQUEST["To"]; ?>" to="+1<?php echo $_REQUEST['FrwdNum']; ?>">
  <?php echo htmlspecialchars(substr(substr($_REQUEST['From'],0,10) . ":" . $_REQUEST['Body'], 0, 160)); ?>
  </Message>
</Response>
```

If your script is www.example.com/answer.php, then give below url as sms url for your twilio number

```
www.example.com/answer.php?FrwdNum=9876543210
```

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with CNAM?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Twilio Lookup](https://www.twilio.com/lookup) to get the CNAM of a number.

Using the REST API, you would specify the `CallerName` property in your GET request: 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups#lookups-caller-name

And the output would look like:

```
{
  "caller_name": "Caller Name",
  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: The api works, but so far, cell phones seem to be excluded from the Twilio Lookup api .

Answer (score 0):

Caller ID/CNAM is only displayed on landlines. Cell phones do NOT support CNAM because carriers defer to your personal contact list to populate names on inbound calls. The terminating carrier (the carrier for the number you are calling) is responsible for displaying CNAM.